# Get notified about layout refresh/change in background thread when the app is actively being used by the user

Tags: android, android-layout, refresh, hook

I am new to android ecosystem. I wanted to know is there a way to get notified when an apps active layout changes for the end user. I am sorry if the question is a repeat, i searched around for what i thought were relevant keywords and could not find an answer. (Note: I dont want to change the UI from a background thread, i just want to get notified when the layout changes according to the user using the app)

Comment: can you post the code.

Comment: I dont have code yet .. I am just thinking of writing an app which would need this functionality ( I started learning android a few days ago and wanted to know if it was possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **custom layout** and basically override its [onDraw](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) method of it which will be called when the layout is been refreshed/updated then get notified from there.

**sample:**

Lets say you have a parent layout using `LinearLayout`.

```
public class Sample2 extends LinearLayout {

    public Sample2(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Sample2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Sample2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.d("UPDATE", "I am REFRESHED"); //will print if this layout is refresh,updated, or invalidated.
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

To use that in the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.sfdsffsdf.Sample2 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


</com.example.sfdsffsdf.Sample2>
```

Comment: I dont know if it is right/wrong as of now, i am accepting this answer as a way of thanking you for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an [OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) on your layout and get notified when the state or visibility of that layout or any of its children get changed:

```
myLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Do something
    }

};
```

Comment: There's also a corresponding removeGlobalOnLayoutListener() method.

Comment: I dont know which is the "correct and most simplest answer" .. i dont have time to check right now ( i have too much learn *and* its for a hobby project). After some more votes are in i will try to revise the correct answer, if necessary.